# I need to convert backend data from an excel dashboard to access

Tags: ms-access, excel, vba

I have a dashboard/tool which uses some backend data to populate a number of charts. These charts dynamically change with the help of VBA (drop-downs, user forms etc.).
My problem is that I need to shift the backend data to an excel database without affecting the functionality of the dashboard/tool.
I have limited experience in VBA and absolutely no experience with MS Access. 
It would be highly appreciated if I could get detailed directions on how to move forward.

Thanks

Comment: In which format is the backend data before you shift it to Excel?

Comment: Basically the data is present in one of the tabs in the excel file. I have to move the data to access and link it to the charts in excel.

Comment: Why do you need the data to be in MsAccess?

Comment: Excel will not be able to handle the size of the data to be processed.

Comment: Could you just copy the "backend" data worksheet(s) to a new workbook to be used by MSAccess?

Comment: @Raystafarian I could do that...but the data would not be linked to the excel spreadsheet. So none of the operations would work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Link MS Access to data in Excel:

This enables you to carry over any operation changes you make in the Excel datasheet into your Access table.

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/import-export-and-link-data-between-access-and-excel-HP001095095.aspx#_Toc269881998

If you don't want to maintain a copy of the data in your Access database, you can instead link to the Excel worksheet. Linking lets you connect to data in Excel without importing it, so that you can view the data in Access. You can update the data in the worksheet when you are working in Excel and your changes will be shown when you view the linked table in Access.

Comment: I need to run some SQL steps on the data. Would it be possible doing this?